# How to use @required annotation on Flutter constructor parameters?

Tags: annotations, widget, flutter

When I annotate a constructor parameter with `@required` IntelliJ shows an error:

> Annotation must be either a const variable reference or const constructor invocation

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

```
class StatusBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const StatusBar({Key key, @required this.text})
      : assert(text != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Annotations need to be imported

Adding at the top of your file

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
```

should fix it.

Annotations the DartAnalyzer understands are provided by the [meta](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/meta) package.

To make it easier for Flutter developers, the Flutter team decided to add the `meta` package to the Flutter SDK and re-export it in `flutter/foundation.dart`. The annotations by flutter are therefore exactly the same as these provided by the meta package and you can as well add `meta` to your dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` and import annotations from there if you prefer. If you want to reuse code between for example AngularDart and Flutter that is the preferred way because code that imports from `package:flutter/...` can't be used in Dart web applications.

Comment: Great answer to avoid issues when using dart repositories for web and android both.

Comment: i am using android studio. why it is does not shown error if i does not pass a variable

Comment: important to note that when you migrate to null-safety, you don't use the required annotation as in '@required' but instead use the required keyword

Answer (score 30):

Please import package "meta" at the beginning of the source file.

```
// @required is defined in the meta.dart package
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
```

Answer (score 5):

Does your code include the following code?

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
```

If your code contains the code above and you get errors, check `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  meta: ^1.4.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

Pay attention to the **meta** section from the above sample.

If the error persists, try the following on the CLI:

```
pub upgrade
```

Comment: Your solution adds new value at all. First, `import 'package:meta/meta.dart';` solution is already provided by someone, second what you have written extra has no meaning when it comes to importing `meta.dart` package because you're not using `meta` in `pubspec.yaml` file. Not sure how you got 2 upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

I found that this problem can happen if your class has a variable called required

```
class TextFieldInputWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final bool required;

  const TextFieldInputWidget({@required this.title, this.required = false});

  @override
  _TextFieldInputWidget createState() => _TextFieldInputWidget();
}
```

Just change the variable name to something else, like "require"

Answer (score 0):

If you have null safety enabled, the required keyword is an actual keyword and not a @ notation:

```
DateTime startDate;
  YourWidget(required this.startDate);
```